# Easy way to test nested model forms with Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, nested-forms, capybara

I've got a nested model for Departments within a Hospitals form.  The code snippet looks like this:

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :hospital do |h| %>
    .
    .
    .       
       <%= h.simple_fields_for :departments do |builder| %>
              <%= render "department_fields", :f => builder %>
            <% end %>
.
.
    <% end %>
```

The _department_fields partial looks like this:

```
<div class="fields">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
    </span>
</div>
```

As a result, the bottom of the form has a place for the user to enter up to three department names.

I am using Rails 3, Cucumber, Capybara and Selenium for integration testing.

Is there a simple way to fill in the repeating fields when testing this form in Cucumber?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write my feature like this:

```
And I fill in the first "Name" with "Cardiology"
And I fill in the second "Name" with "Radiology"
```

Is there some way to easily approximate this in Cucumber/Capybara?  Has someone already figured out some steps to address this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capybara has a way to deal with this by using within. For example:

```
And I fill in "Name" with "Radiology" within "fields"
```

For example, if you have divs with ids of 'hospital_fields' and 'department_fields' around both form areas, you could do something like this to differentiate which field you are filling in:

```
And I fill in "Name" with "Cardiology" within "hospital_fields"
And I fill in "Name" with "Radiology" within "department_fields"
```

You can also be more specific by using the text field id instead of the field label name. For example, if the first text field has an id of 'hospital_name' and the second has an id of 'hospital_department_name' you could do the following:

```
And I fill in "hospital_name" with "Cardiology"
And I fill in "hospital_deparment_name" with "Radiology"
```

**UPDATE**: You can also add a custom cucumber step to use numbered inputs:

```
When /^(?:|I )fill in the (\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |num, name, value|
  find(:xpath, ".//form/input[@name='#{name}'][#{num}]").set(value)
end

And I fill in the 1st "name" with "Cardiology"
And I fill in the 2nd "name" with "Radiology"
```

**UPDATE**: To match with the label use this expression:

```
find(:xpath, ".//input[@id=//label[contains(.,'#{name}')]/@for][#{num}]").set(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I might not have explained the problem sufficiently.  You see the "Name" field repeats at least 4 times within "department_fields"; this way the user can enter up to 4 departments for the hospital.  So specifying "within 'department_fields'" is useful but does not solve my problem.  Specifying by id is also problematic, because the user has the option of adding more than 4 departments, at which point, the test suite seems to tack on a random looking id number, so I cannot fully test this way.  Besides, the ids are really ugly.

Comment: @Kevin, I've updated my answer to deal with that situation as well.

Comment: Thanks for the code Pan.  I'm getting an error Unable to find './/form/input[@name='Name'][2]' (Capybara::ElementNotFound),  but I think I get the gist of it.  Something in the structure of my page must be throwing it off.

Comment: Make sure name is not capitalized, since @name is referring to the HTML attribute. You can also make the XPATH expression more general using //input instead of //form/input.

Comment: I realized the problem - I want to search on label and not name (doh!)  I tried the following, which I think gets close, but does not quite work:   find(:xpath, ".//input[@id=//label[contains(.,'#{name}')][#{num}]/@for]").set(value).  I can find the first occurrence but not the later ones.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that uses the label instead.

Comment: Thanks Pan, but that one doesn't work for me either.  I think the reason is that each of my inputs is wrapped by at least one layer of "div".  That means that none of the inputs are siblings, and the [] predicate selects the nth occurrence of sibling elements.  So I think I get many hits when num = 1, but no occurrences when num = 2.

Comment: cont.  don't know if that made sense.  My workaround is to avoid the label altogether and look for the nth input in my departments fieldset:

Comment: find(:xpath, ".//fieldset/div[#{num}]/div/input").set(value).  Still, I'm curious if there's a way to find the nth label, regardless of ancestry, rather than the nth node of a specific parent.

Comment: Unless the ids are actually unique instead of array elements, for example name[1], name[2] instead of name[], name[] there isn't a way to find the label for a specific input element unless you have a better understanding of the structure of the page, since all the for attributes on the labels are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Pan is going to help you find the answer to your issue.

However I'd like to add my two cents here. As it has been recommended by many people, including Dan North [1], Ben Mabey [2], Jonas Nicklas [3] and even Aslask Hellesøy recommending you to remove web_steps.rb [4], you should try not to write cucumber scenarios with steps surfacing implementation details.

```
When I fill in "Name" with "Cardiology"
```

This is about filling an HTML form input based on its label or ID or whatever... This is implementation.

I guess you could go with steps such as:

```
When I create a department called "Cardiology"
And I create a department called "Radiology"
```

Dan North even recommends having only one "event" [5] (a "When" step):

```
When I create departments called "Cardiology" and "Radiology"
```

All the form/html handling is then encapsulated within a single step definition. And of course, there you can apply the XPath expression Pan suggested above.

- [1] http://dannorth.net/2011/01/31/whose-domain-is-it-anyway/
- [2] http://benmabey.com/2008/05/19/imperative-vs-declarative-scenarios-in-user-stories.html
- [3] http://elabs.se/blog/15-you-re-cuking-it-wrong
- [4] https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails/commit/e8d8ddb504b11452a0dc8946316faecc26915f17
- [5] http://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story/

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I hadn't considered the idea of replacing or customizing web_steps.rb for each scenario, but I can see how that would improve the readability of my features.  I'll need to think about this.

Comment: I'm glad it helps! I really think writing "good" features is essential. Particularly if you use them as a true communication tool.

Comment: This is solid advice. Have in mind that unless you are sharing the Cucumber tests with stakeholders, it's significantly more productive to [use RSpec instead](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/index.html#getting-started-%F0%9F%9A%80).

Else, you could at least try to encapsulate the complexity in the steps using a tool like [__Capybara Test Helpers__](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/migrating_from_cucumber/index.html)